# How to resolve these errors form updated Node & npm versions ..?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack

I update the Node latest version to 15.0.1 & npm 7.0.3. After i installed node modules and run my project with npm start its showing these type of errors....

> cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --config webpack.dev.js

node:events:304
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^

Error: spawn webpack-dev-server ENOENT
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:269:19)
at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:465:16)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:80:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:275:12)
at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:465:16)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:80:21) {
errno: -2,
code: 'ENOENT',
syscall: 'spawn webpack-dev-server',
path: 'webpack-dev-server',
spawnargs: [ '--open', '--config', 'webpack.dev.js' ]
}
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --config webpack.dev.js

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/krishnasai/.npm/_logs/2020-10-28T09_44_19_855Z-debug.log

Comment: I have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

feels to me that you installed `cross-env` globally, and it might break whenever you switch node versions.

i would advise you to have `cross-env` in the dependency of your project. you can do that by installing `cross-env` and specify that you would like to save it in your `package.json`.

try this

```sh
npm install --save-dev cross-env
```

then try again to run your project.